# How can I utilize a specific variable based on a conditional statement?

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2010

I have a macro that displays a `UserForm` that will create a reconciliation report depending on which report the user decides they want to be generated. (i.e. if the user selects a reconciliation for **credit cards**, a **credit card** report will be generated. If they select **Checks** & **Credit Cards**, a report will be created for both the **credit cards** and the **checks** -- In the same master report summary)

Once the `CheckBoxes` for either of the reports are selected in the initial form (or deselected) a `Boolean` variable for the account is toggled. Once the user proceeds with the selected reports, the report will be generated for each selection. (The first sheet is the summary, each consecutive sheet contains the source files and the balancing calculations for each report -- capped is the summary sheet)

***Refer to the first image.***

..

After the report is completed, if there are differences found between the two accounts that are being reconciled (bank statement vs. our accounting records), then another `UserForm` will be displayed showing the differences, presented in two separate `ListBoxes`; one `ListBox` contains the extra values from our records, the other `ListBox` contains the extra values from the Bank Statement.

***Refer to the second & third image.***

..

The post-report `UserForm` has 2 `Buttons` for each `ListBox`; one `Button` allows the user to remove the selected [`ListBox`] item from the list if it balances out to an item/multiple items in the other `ListBox`. If it does not match, they will have to reflect it in our records, and the second `Button` allows them to reflect having done so in the daily reconciliation report.

For the macro, I have created variables formatted as "BWVariable", "ChVariable", "eChVariable" or "CCVariable" for each possible report to affect only that report's items. Through my testing, however, I have only used the BWVariables as it was easiest to test with.

Now that it's finished, I want outcome of the `Button_Click()` Event to use the BWVariables if the BWReport is true, and if the CCReport is true, I want it to use the CCVariables. Is there a way to use specific variables depending on the output of a conditional statement?

..

Here's the code that is most specifically affected:

```
Private Sub RemovedfromGPButton_Click()
    Dim BWItem As Double

    For lItem = BWListBox.ListCount - 1 To 0 Step -1
        If BWListBox.Selected(lItem) Then
            BWItem = BWListBox.List(lItem, 0)
            BWListBox.RemoveItem lItem
            If BWAddedGPSum2 Is Nothing Then
                Set BWAddedGPSum2 = Range(BWGPSum.Offset(1, -3), BWGPSum.Offset(1, 1))
                BWAddedGPSum2.Insert Shift:=xlDown
                Set BWAddedGPSum2 = Range(BWGPSum.Offset(1, -3), BWGPSum.Offset(1, 1))
                BWAddedGPSum2.Interior.ColorIndex = 0
                BWAddedGPSum2.Insert Shift:=xlDown
                Set BWAddedGPSum2 = Range(BWGPSum.Offset(1, -3), BWGPSum.Offset(1, 1))
                BWAddedGPSum2.Interior.ColorIndex = 0
                Set BWAddedGPTitle2 = Range(BWGPSum.Offset(1, -2), BWGPSum.Offset(1, -1))
                With BWAddedGPTitle2
                    .MergeCells = True
                    .HorizontalAlignment = xlRight
                    .VerticalAlignment = xlCenter
                End With
                    BWAddedGPTitle2.Value = "Added to Deposit:"
                Set BWAddedGPSum2 = BWGPSum.Offset(1, 0)
                    If BWAddedGPSum Is Nothing Then
                        BWAddedGPSum2.Borders(xlEdgeBottom).LineStyle = xlContinuous
                    End If
                If BWGPSum.Offset(-1, 0).Text = "" Then
                    Set BWGPSum = BWVariance.Offset(-2, 0)
                        Range(BWGPSum.Offset(0, -1), BWGPSum.Offset(0, -2)).MergeCells = True
                        BWGPSum.Offset(0, -1).HorizontalAlignment = xlRight
                        BWGPSum.Offset(0, -2).Value = "Total:"
                        BWGPSum.Interior.ColorIndex = 6
                End If
            End If
            BWAddedGPSum2.Value = Format((BWAddedGPSum2.Value + BWItem), "$#,##0.00")
            BWGPSum.Value = Format(Application.WorksheetFunction.Sum(BWGPSum.Offset(-1, 0).End(xlUp), _
                                   BWGPSum.Offset(-1, 0)), "$#,##0.00")
            Call DetermineVariance
            If Me.BWListBox.MultiSelect = fmMultiSelectSingle Then
                Exit For
            End If

        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

..

**First Image:**

[image: This is the First Image:]

..

**Second Image:**

[image: This is the Second Image:]

..

**Third Image:**

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no way to query/refer to a variable name part in VBA

So I'd suggest you to:

- use a `User Defined Type` (say we call it "Report") whose fields names matches your variables names *constant* part (`ListBox`, `Item`, `AddedGPSum`, `AddedGPSum2`,...)
- declare a `Public` variable (say we calle it `REP`) of type "Report" in any of your modules

  it'll be used/shared between userforms
- declare userform scoped properly named variables (`BW`, `Ch`, `eCh`, `CC`) of type "Report" in the `ReportGenerator` userform

this way your `RemovedfromGPButton_Click` sub code will have minor modifications:

- wrap it inside a `With REP` and `End With` block
- replace `BW` with `.`

in a bit more detail:

---

**Main sub**

here follows your main sub *essential* excerpt:

```
Option Explicit

Type Report '<-- define the User Defined Type 'Report'
    ListBox As MSForms.ListBox
    Item As String
    AddedGPSum As Range
    AddedGPSum2 As Range
    AddedGPTitle2 As Range
    GPSum As Range
    Variance As Range
    '
    ' and whatever else you may need
    '
End Type

Public REP As Report '<--| declare a Public variable of type 'Report'


Sub main() 'this is the sub that will exploit 'ReportGenerator' Userform

    '
    ' your code preceeding 'ReportGenerator' Userform exploitation
    '

    With ReportGenerator '<--| now you load the 'ReportGenerator' Userform...
        ' code to initialize/set userform controls (you may want to take it into its 'UserForm_Initialize' sub)

        .Show '<--| ... and show it

        '
        ' possible code to exploit 'ReportGenerator' Userform outcome
        '
    End With

    '
    ' your code after 'ReportGenerator' Userform exploitation
    '


End Sub
```

---

**ReportGenerator Userform**

here follows your `ReportGenerator` userform code *essential* excerpt:

```
Option Explicit

Dim BW As Report, Ch As Report, eCh As Report, CC As Report '<--| declare Userform scoped variables. They'll be available throughout the whole 'ReportGenerator' userform subs and functions


Private Sub OKButton_Click() '<--| change "OKButton" with your actual 'ReportGenerator' userform button name with "OK" caption

    With Me '<--| refer to 'ReportGenerator' userform
        Select Case True '<--| check for the first checked checkbox...
            Case .CheckBox1
                REP = BW '<--|... and assign the proper variable of type "Report" to the public variable REP of type "Report"
            Case .CheckBox2
                REP = Ch '<--|... and assign the proper variable of type "Report" to the public variable REP of type "Report"
            Case .CheckBox3
                REP = eCh '<--|... and assign the proper variable of type "Report" to the public variable REP of type "Report"
            Case .CheckBox4
                REP = CC '<--|... and assign the proper variable of type "Report" to the public variable REP of type "Report"
        End Select
        .Hide '<--| hide the 'ReportGenerator' userform before showing "Unmatched_Summary" one

        Unmatched_Summary.Show ' <--| load and show "Unmatched_Summary" userform
        Unload Unmatched_Summary  ' <--| unload "Unmatched_Summary" userform

        .Show ' <--| show 'ReportGenerator' userform again
    End With


End Sub


Private Sub UserForm_Initialize() '<--| this runs at Userform loading time
    With Me '<--| refer to 'ReportGenerator' userform
        Set BW.ListBox = .ListBox1 '<--| set BW listbox to appropriate variable of type "Report"
        Set Ch.ListBox = .ListBox2 '<--| set Ch its listbox to appropriate variable of type "Report"
        Set eCh.ListBox = .ListBox3 '<--| set eCH listbox to appropriate variable of type "Report"
        Set CC.ListBox = .ListBox4 '<--| set CC listbox to appropriate variable of type "Report"
    End With
End Sub
```

---

**Unmatched Summary userform**

here follows your `UnmatchedSummary` userform code *essential* excerpt

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub RemovedfromGPButton_Click()
    Dim lItem As Long

    With REP '<--| refer the Public variable of tipe "Report" that has been previuosly set to the proper one in 'ReportGenerator' just before 'Unmatched_Summary.Show' statement
        For lItem = .ListBox.ListCount - 1 To 0 Step -1
            If .ListBox.Selected(lItem) Then
                .Item = .ListBox.List(lItem, 0)
                .ListBox.RemoveItem lItem
                If .AddedGPSum2 Is Nothing Then
                    Set .AddedGPSum2 = Range(.GPSum.Offset(1, -3), .GPSum.Offset(1, 1))
                    .AddedGPSum2.Insert Shift:=xlDown
                    Set .AddedGPSum2 = Range(.GPSum.Offset(1, -3), .GPSum.Offset(1, 1))
                    .AddedGPSum2.Interior.ColorIndex = 0
                    .AddedGPSum2.Insert Shift:=xlDown
                    Set .AddedGPSum2 = Range(.GPSum.Offset(1, -3), .GPSum.Offset(1, 1))
                    .AddedGPSum2.Interior.ColorIndex = 0
                    Set .AddedGPTitle2 = Range(.GPSum.Offset(1, -2), .GPSum.Offset(1, -1))
                    With .AddedGPTitle2
                        .MergeCells = True
                        .HorizontalAlignment = xlRight
                        .VerticalAlignment = xlCenter
                    End With
                        .AddedGPTitle2.value = "Added to Deposit:"
                    Set .AddedGPSum2 = .GPSum.Offset(1, 0)
                        If .AddedGPSum Is Nothing Then
                            .AddedGPSum2.Borders(xlEdgeBottom).LineStyle = xlContinuous
                        End If
                    If .GPSum.Offset(-1, 0).Text = "" Then
                        Set .GPSum = .Variance.Offset(-2, 0)
                            Range(.GPSum.Offset(0, -1), .GPSum.Offset(0, -2)).MergeCells = True
                            .GPSum.Offset(0, -1).HorizontalAlignment = xlRight
                            .GPSum.Offset(0, -2).value = "Total:"
                            .GPSum.Interior.ColorIndex = 6
                    End If
                End If
                .AddedGPSum2.value = Format((.AddedGPSum2.value + .Item), "$#,##0.00")
                .GPSum.value = Format(Application.WorksheetFunction.Sum(.GPSum.Offset(-1, 0).End(xlUp), _
                                       .GPSum.Offset(-1, 0)), "$#,##0.00")
    '            Call DetermineVariance
                If .ListBox.MultiSelect = fmMultiSelectSingle Then Exit For

            End If
        Next lItem
    End With

End Sub
```

and, as you can see, it took very little modifications as compared to your original `RemovedfromGPButton_Click()` sub

**Edit to check all checkboxes**

to check and act for all checkboxes here follows how changes the relevant excerpt of `ReportGenerator Userform` code:

```
With Me '<--| refer to 'ReportGenerator' userform
    .Hide '<--| hide the 'ReportGenerator' userform before showing "Unmatched_Summary" one
    If .CheckBox1 Then
        REP = BW '<--|... and assign the proper variable of type "Report" to the public variable REP of type "Report"
        Unmatched_Summary.Show ' <--| load and show "Unmatched_Summary" userform
    End If
    If .CheckBox2 Then
        REP = Ch '<--|... and assign the proper variable of type "Report" to the public variable REP of type "Report"
        Unmatched_Summary.Show ' <--| load and show "Unmatched_Summary" userform
    End If
    If .CheckBox3 Then
        REP = eCh '<--|... and assign the proper variable of type "Report" to the public variable REP of type "Report"
        Unmatched_Summary.Show ' <--| load and show "Unmatched_Summary" userform
    End If
    If .CheckBox4 Then
        REP = CC '<--|... and assign the proper variable of type "Report" to the public variable REP of type "Report"
        Unmatched_Summary.Show ' <--| load and show "Unmatched_Summary" userform
    End Select

    Unload Unmatched_Summary  ' <--| unload "Unmatched_Summary" userform

    .Show ' <--| show 'ReportGenerator' userform again
End With
```

Comment: With the purpose of the macro to allow user's to run multiple reports at the same time (multiple `checkboxes = true`) Would defining `REP = ch`, `REP = bw`, etc. negate the ability to run multiple reports ?

Comment: No, it won't. In `OKButton_Click()` of `ReportGenerator Userform` you just turn the `Select Case` block into a loop through checkboxes and that's it.

Comment: I am not too familiar with `Type` and `Property` yet, but I am practicing... With this `Type`, when the user clicks both the BW CheckBox and the CC CheckBox, how would the discrepancies reported in the two ListBoxes remain separate? (There are 4 balances that will occur if the user selects all 4; these balances have their own separate discrepancies that cannot be interchanged with the other balances, otherwise the report accounts will not be reconciled). I see it reads if CheckBox1 is checked, it sets `REP = BW`, but what would then allow this to be repeated with the next report (CC)?

Comment: instead of using the `Select case` block you must _loop_ between checkboxes or code a sequence of `If .CheckBoxN.. Then .. End If`: see edited answer

Comment: I really wish I could vote this twice because you have answered both my original question, as well as my second question I was really stuck on! One thing I'm not sure how to get passed is when the `UnmatchedSummary` form is displayed, it is Modeless, allowing the rest of the code to continue. Is it possible to have the form Modeless, or at least allow the window to remain visible while the user navigates the sheets freely, only to continue the remainder of the code upon completion? The form will be utilized for all queued reports. (Not within the form code, but the Main method)